# FFMPEG - Display time taken to convert

Tags: ffmpeg

How is it possible to display the time taken to convert a video using FFMPEG ?

i am using the below command and the time returned as benchmark is not exactly the time taken to complete the conversion.. i am confused how can it be missing in a such nice tool.

```
ffmpeg -cpuflags -sse-sse2-sse3-sse3slow-sse4.1-sse4.2+mmx -i E:/MSC/test.flv ^
  -benchmark E:/MSC/testmmx.mp4
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use Bash it has the `time` command

```
time: time [-p] pipeline
    Report time consumed by pipeline's execution.

    Execute PIPELINE and print a summary of the real time, user CPU time,
    and system CPU time spent executing PIPELINE when it terminates.
```

Example

```
$ time ffmpeg -i infile outfile

real    0m3.682s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.000s
```

I offer Cygwin for Windows, which includes Bash and `time`

[`bitbucket.org/svnpenn/a/downloads`](https://bitbucket.org/svnpenn/a/downloads)

Comment: Tnx for this but i couldnt get the time when running the command with time or -t

what i need is, after running the script

ffmpeg -cpuflags -sse-sse2-sse3-sse3slow-sse4.1+sse4.2+mmx -i C:/test1.mkv -benchmark C:/testmmx.mp4

at the completion time it should display the duration of video conversion.